# Jacoco how to correctly exclude package

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I am using the Jacoco Maven plugin version 0.8.1 (With Java 8 / Maven 3.1.0).
Cannot get Jacoco to work with path exclusions.
I would like to exclude these packages :

- `my.package.model`
- `my.package.exception`

What I tried :

```
<build>
      <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>  
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>my.package.model</exclude>
                        <exclude>my.package.exception</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
      </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>my.package.model</exclude>
                        <exclude>my.package.exception</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</reporting>
```

And also (for the `excludes` part) :

```
<excludes>
     <exclude>my.package.model**</exclude>
     <exclude>my.package.exception**</exclude>
</excludes>

<excludes>
     <exclude>my/package/model/**/*</exclude>
     <exclude>my/package/exception/**/*</exclude>
</excludes>

<excludes>
     <exclude>*/my/package/model/**/*</exclude>
     <exclude>*/my/package/exception/**/*</exclude>
</excludes>

<excludes>
     <exclude>**/my/package/model/**/*</exclude>
     <exclude>**/my/package/exception/**/*</exclude>
</excludes>

<excludes>
     <exclude>**/my/package/model/**</exclude>
     <exclude>**/my/package/exception/**</exclude>
</excludes>

<excludes>
     <exclude>**/my/package/model/*</exclude>
     <exclude>**/my/package/exception/*</exclude>
</excludes>

<excludes>
     <exclude>**/model/*</exclude>
     <exclude>**/exception/*</exclude>
</excludes>

<excludes>
     <exclude>**/model**</exclude>
     <exclude>**/exception**</exclude>
</excludes>
```

Impossible to remove these packages from the final report ... Frustrating.

I read :

- [Filter JaCoCo coverage reports with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887805/filter-jacoco-coverage-reports-with-gradle)
- [Jacoco exclude classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038034/jacoco-exclude-classes)
- [Jacoco exclude classes from report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042709/jacoco-exclude-classes-from-report)
  ...

Nothing work.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have that and it works (notice that the `excludes` are in `execution/configuration` and that everything is in `pluginManagement`):

```xml
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/integration-coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>weblogic/*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/integration-coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>my/company/package/db/entity/**/*.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: Ok thanks ! So I have updated my `<reporting>` section, removed the configuration from `<plugins>` section and added the full path of package with `*.class`. It was necessary to add the `class` extension.

Comment: The folder structure also matters : for example : **/webapp/**/* will exclude all files under webapp directory. The "**" is for directory and "*" is for file. If you just have **/webapp/* then it won't exclude the folders under webapp folder.

Comment: Looks like sonar exclusion is also needed if you want to exclude from sonar coverage. By including this in properties section which is picked up by Sonar automatically  : <properties>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
        **/domains/**/*,
        **/webapp/**/*
    </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
</properties>

Answer (score 7):

As per the example that you have shared, this change in the POM file should work:

```
<build>
      <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>  
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>my/package/model/**/*.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>my/package/exception/**/*.class</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
      </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>my/package/model/**/*.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>my/package/exception/**/*.class</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I usually put the `prepare-agent` goal and `report` goal inside the same plugin. This helps me to put the exclude packages under one section only. This is how my pom file looks:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>my/package/model/**/*.class</exclude>
                    <exclude>my/package/exception/**/*.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>  
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```